# how to Insert into table from another table after sorting data of first table in greenplum

Tags: sql, greenplum

I'm doing something in greenplum :

```
insert into hctest.tab1
select
a::bytea,
b::varchar,
c::varchar
from hctest.ext_city2;
```

existing values in table tab1 :

```
    id   |   name    | address
  -------+-----------+-----------
   10011 | John      | Serang
   10012 | Calvin    | Tangerang
   10013 | Layla     | Jakarta
```

values in table ext_city2 :

```
  a    |     b     |   c
-------+-----------+-----------
 10011 | John      | Serang
 10012 | Calvin    | Tangerang
 10013 | Layla     | Jakarta
 10014 | Kevin     | Bandung
 10015 | Rudy      | Bali
```

there's some duplicate row if i load all data from `ext_city2` to `tab1`. I just want to load the unduplicate row to the `tab1`.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to insert new records from `ext_city2` which are not already there in `tab1` table.

Try this:

```
insert into hctest.tab1 
(
 select a::bytea,b::varchar,c::varchar  from hctest.ext_city2 ec where not exists
 (select * from hctest.tab1 tb where tb.id=ec.a::bytea)
);
```

Comment: i've try this but i got this error massage : "operator doesn't exist: integer = text"
I think because `ec.a` is text and `tb.id` is bytea.

Comment: Then you can use `CAST ( expression AS target_type)`

Comment: can you share the schema of both the tables and what error are you getting?

Comment: sorry.. i've found my mistake, there is a conflict data type with my table.. thanks for this helpfull answer..